# Find matching records in DataTable as fast as possible

Tags: c#

I have C# `DataTables` with very large numbers of rows, and in my importer app I must query these hundreds of thousands of times in a given import. So I'm trying to find the fastest possible way to search. Thus far I am puzzling over very strange results. First, here are 2 different approaches I have been experimenting with:

**APPROACH #1**

```cs
public static bool DoesRecordExist(string keyColumn, string keyValue, DataTable dt)
{
    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
       return dt.Select($"{keyColumn} = '{SafeTrim(keyValue)}'").Count() > 0;
    else
       return false;
}
```

**APPROACH #2**

```cs
public static bool DoesRecordExist(string keyColumn, string keyValue, DataTable dt)
{
    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        int counter = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn]), keyValue, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).Count();
        return counter > 0;
    } 
    else
       return false;
}
```

In a mock test I run each method 15,000 times, handing in hardcoded data. This is apples-to-apples, a fair test. Approach #1 is dramatically faster. But in actual app execution, Approach #1 is dramatically *slower*.

Why the counterintuitive results? Is there some other *faster* way to query datatables that I haven't tried?

> EDIT: The reason I use datatables as opposed to other types of
>   collections is because all my datasources are either MySQL tables or
>   CSV files. So datatables seemed like a logical choice. Some of these
>   tables contain 10+ columns, so different types of collections seemed
>   an awkward match.

Comment: I don't want this to sound like a "person asks X, you answer 'use Y' thing", but: can you clarify whether `DataTable` is an important part here? There are many options that would seem far more tempting for this scenario, such as dictionaries, hash-sets, etc; I just want to understand *why* we have a `DataTable` here - so we can understand the context

Comment: btw; as a speed improvement to #2: a) fetch the `DataColumn` *first* (`var col = dt.Columns[keyColumn];` ... `r[col]` ..., and b) use `Any()` - you only care whether there are 0 or at least 1 - no point counting past 1; so: `return dt.AsEnumerable().Where(...).Any();`

Comment: I would first switch to `Rows.Any()` rather than `Rows.Count`.

Comment: `Is there some other faster ways?`, yes there is. But it may require implementation changes and code tweaking. If performance is the key here, there are hash-sets, dictionaries,hash sets. It's your pick now!

Comment: Marc: I edited my question to answer yours. All: `.Any()` does give me a slight performance boost. I'll take it! Can someone answer the question so I can accept?

Comment: why not just let database engine do its job

Answer (score 2):

If you want a faster access and still want to stick to the DataTables, use a dictionary to store the row numbers for given keys. Here I assume that each key is unique in the DataTable. If not, you would have to use a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` or `Dictionary<string, HashSet<int>>` to store the indexes.

```
var indexes = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
    indexes.Add((string)dt.Rows[i].Column(keyColumn), i);
}
```

Now you can access a row in a super fast way with

```
var row = dt.Rows[indexes[theKey]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar issue except that I need the actual First Occurrence of a matching row.

Using the .Select.FirstOrDefault (Approach 1) takes 38 minutes to run.
Using the .Where.FirstOrDefault (Approach 2) takes 6 minutes to run.

In a similar situation where I didn't need the FirstOrDefault, but just needed to find and work with the uniquely matching record, what I found to be the fastest by far is to use a HashTable where the Key is the Combined Values of any Columns you are trying to match, and the Value is the Data Row itself. Finding a Match is near instant.

The Function is

```
 public Hashtable ConvertToLookup(DataTable myDataTable, params string[] pKeyFieldNames)
    {
        Hashtable myLookup = new Hashtable(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);  //Makes the Key Case Insensitive
        foreach (DataRow myRecord in myDataTable.Rows)
        {
            string myHashKey = "";
            foreach (string strKeyFieldName in pKeyFieldNames)
            {
                myHashKey += Convert.ToString(myRecord[strKeyFieldName]).Trim();
            }

            if (myLookup.ContainsKey(myHashKey) == false)
            {
                myLookup.Add(myHashKey, myRecord);
            }
        }

        return myLookup;
    }
```

The usage is...

```
//Build the Lookup Table
Hashtable myLookUp = ConvertToLookup(myDataTable, "Col1Name", "Col2Name");

//Use it
if (myLookUp.ContainsKey(mySearchForValue) == true)
{
  DataRow myRecord = (DataRow)myLookUp[mySearchForValue]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All. BINGO! Wanted to share as a different answer just because my previous might be suited for a bit of a different approach. In this scenario, I was able to go from 8 MINUTES, down to 6 SECONDS, not using either approaches...

Again, the key is a HashTable, or in my case a dictionary because I had multiple records. To recap, for me, I needed to delete 1 row from my DataTable for every matching record I found in another DataTable. With the goal that in the end, my First Datatable only contained the "Missing" records.

This uses a different function...

```
    // -----------------------------------------------------------
    // Creates a Dictionary with Grouping Counts from a DataTable
    public Dictionary<string, Int32> GroupBy(DataTable myDataTable, params string[] pGroupByFieldNames)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Int32> myGroupBy = new Dictionary<string, Int32>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);  //Makes the Key Case Insensitive
        foreach (DataRow myRecord in myDataTable.Rows)
        {
            string myKey = "";
            foreach (string strGroupFieldName in pGroupByFieldNames)
            {
                myKey += Convert.ToString(myRecord[strGroupFieldName]).Trim();
            }

            if (myGroupBy.ContainsKey(myKey) == false)
            {
                myGroupBy.Add(myKey, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                myGroupBy[myKey] += 1;
            }
        }

        return myGroupBy;
    }
```

Now.. say you have a Table of Records that you want to use as the "Match Values" based on Col1 and Col2

```
Dictionary<string, Int32> myQuickLookUpCount = GroupBy(myMatchTable, "Col1", "Col2");
```

And now the magic. We are looping through your Primary Table, and removing 1 instance of a record for each instance in the Matching Table. This is the part that took 8 minutes with Approach #2, or 38 minutes with Approach #1.. but now only takes seconds.

```
myDataTable.AcceptChanges(); //Trick that allows us to delete during a ForEach!
foreach (DataRow myDataRow in myDataTable.Rows)
{
   //Grab the Key Values
   string strKey1Value = Convert.ToString(myDataRow ["Col1"]);
   string strKey2Value = Convert.ToString(myDataRow ["Col2"]);

   if (myQuickLookUpCount.TryGetValue(strKey1Value + strKey2Value, out Int32 intTotalCount) == true && intTotalCount > 0)
   {
     myDataTable.Delete();  //Mark our Row to Delete
     myQuickLookUpCount [strKey1Value + strKey2Value ] -= 1;  //Decrement our Counter
    }
 }

 myDataTable.AcceptChanges(); //Commits our changes and actually deletes the rows.
```